# Symfony2 sharing entities in multiple bundles

Tags: symfony

In my project I have `API Bundle` and `Dashboard Bundle` where I reuse Entities like `Client`, `User`, `Store` etc in both bundles. All entities are in `API Bundle` at the moment, however I have a feeling that they should be stored in a different Bundle, something like `Generic Bundle`.

Does anyone has a `Best Practice` for that?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650688/symfony2-share-entity-between-bundles-with-different-relationships) question about relationships, but it speaks about relationships and not Best Practice.

Thanks.

Comment: First of I would create one application (Application specific bundle) which would then import API Bundle (Reusable) and Dashboard Bundle (Reusable) as composer packages in vendors directory. This was you have two decoupled bundles. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is really one best practice here but the key is re-usability. Let's say down the road for some reason you decide to run the API & Dashboard as 2 separate services. Having a UserBundle with your Client & User Entities means you'll just need to install that on both services along with either the API or Dashboard bundle. You could then also have a service with only your UserBundle that handles the login, ect... Same thing for the Store, I would personally decouple that as much as I could.

But the real question is if it is necessary ? Would you reuse that UserBundle in another project ? Do you plan on splitting the project as services down the road ?

Ultimately the specifics are really up to you, a GenericBundle could be all you need or you might have enough to separate into UserBundle & StoreBundle for example.

Comment: Yes I understand clearly what you say. So for reusability in an other project it would be better to decouple those entities in a different bundle(s) & if I want to `Bundle 1` & `Bundle 2` be services, those would use `Bundle Reusable Entities` to handle `Client` or `Store`. I hope I understood what I have to do. 
As 2 Bundles right now are using same entities I feel that those Entities should be stored in a different bundle and any Controller functionality that would be the same, I would always inherit a `ClientBundle/ClientController` in my `DashboardBundle/ClientController`.